# PHP insert data in database

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I've save function in php

```
$post = $this->request->post('event');

    $events = ORM::factory('Tasks_Manage')->values();

        try {

            $return = array();
            foreach ($events as $event) {

                $title = $event['name']['taskName'];
                $time = $event['time'];

                $return[] = $event;

             $event->save();
         }
            return array(

                'return' => $return;
```

Data, are existing in headers but array in response is empty. Please help

Comment: what is the output when you: 
   `var_dump($events)?`

Comment: does `ORM::factory('Tasks_Manage')->values();` return an object that contains a save method?

Comment: while var_dump($events) ,array is returned properly. Metdod save no return data

Comment: You have `error display` on? [(how to)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) That `try { ...} catch { ...}` syntax looks odd?

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn->insert('user', array('username' => 'jwage'));
```

// INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?) (jwage)

Comment: Is this really an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Im was rebuild my code

```
$events = $this->request->post('event'); 

    $h = ORM::factory('Tasks_Manage'); 

    $return = array(); 

    foreach($events as $event) {

        $title = $event['name']['taskName'];
        $time = $event['time'];

        $return[] = $event;
        $h->values( array(
            'event_id' => $title,
            'time'  => $time,
        ))->save();

        }

        return array(
            'event' => $events);
```

Now i can save value in database, but only one record. Why i cant save few records simultaneously? In console response and preview send correct

Answer (score 0):

You don't get all entries of database. Use **find_all()** method (using **values()** method is wrong)

```
$events = ORM::factory('Tasks_Manage')->find_all();
```